# CakePHP highly integrated SignUp Form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, cakephp, transactions

I just wonder how to build up a signup form like this with cakephp 2.x:
A member can have multiple workingtimes and multiple vacationtimes.
There should be one large signup form with one submit button and 3 visually separated areas: memberdetails, workingtimes, vacationtimes.
During signup a member should enter his personal data inside memberdetails and add arbitrary workingtimes as well as arbitrary vacationtimes in the designated areas before hitting the submit button. All the entered times should be listed tabular inside the form before submitting the whole form. At some point the memberdetails, workingtimes and vacationtimes look good and the user submits the form(I know that this is only the ideal situation and there are missing some functions).
My first approach was including the forms for adding workingtimes and vacationtimes inside the members form and send serialized form data via Ajax-POST to the other controller actions (Workingtime->add, Vacationtime->add) and also load the whole related data with something like a crud index function via Ajax and inject the response into the signup form without reloading it. This seems to keep things like validation, security component or the view layout simple, because most of the work will be done by cakephp and not with javascript, but I think it only works if I have allready a database ID for the member - after this I can store workingtimes and vacationtimes. Like allready said, I would prefer one form with one submit button and be able to cancel the whole registration even if there where allready added workingtimes or vacationtimes.

So what is the cake way to achive an integrated form like this? Is it useful to start a transaction and create a dummy member when the form is loading? And then use the ID of this dummy record to store the related workingtimes and vacationtimes? And when hitting the submit button the dummy member is updated to store the entered personal data and everything can be commited? Or should the entered related model data only be validated without saving and then just cache these data for a final transaction block?
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for this is to manage states. Allow user to enter the basic data, change state, and then you can ask for more information but you will have already a user id to associate and match info. If the user comes back later it will have the current state already.

With Cake, a Component would help you to go from one step to another. Each data you enter should be validated.